# working with CVS server remotely

Tags: cvs

I know. Who uses CVS these days, right? Well I'm joining an existing project where CVS is used. I have to work remotely, like 6 hour flight away. Apparently, there will be the pain of network - a lot of cvs commands rely on the server being available.

My question is: is there any trick when dealing with such a situation? Have a local cvs repository mirror? Is it possible to locally work with other system like svn, git and bridge the transition to CVS automatically?

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13425332/311635.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run CVS in parallel with a ("centralized") DVCS repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401887/how-to-run-cvs-in-parallel-with-a-centralized-dvcs-repository)